# How to disable/remove mouse click mapping to Windows Flip 3D?

Tags: windows, aero

When I press left and right mouse button at the same time, windows 7 arranges all windows in 3d space diagonally for me to pick one. I don't know what it's called.

Any idea on how to disable it?

Comment: I would like to know how to enable this feature. It's equivalent to pressing `windows key`+`tab`

Comment: Do you know what it's called because when I play a game windows minimizes the game every time.

Comment: I believe it's called `Flip3D`

Comment: If you started to get this problem earlier then there is a good solution that you can restore your system. Also if you encountered the problem after installing any new software then try to uninstall the program and see if it works, also you can check the settings change by the program and try to make changes in settings of the newly installed program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you have a 3rd-party or a mouse manufacturer program that had remapped the combo mouse clicks to Windows Flip 3D (<kbd>Windows Key</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>). To solve such problem, you need to locate the program and removed the mapping.

If you would like to disable Flip 3D completely then follow the instructions below. Note that this doesn't "technically" solve the mapping issue. However, since it does disable the Windows feature, it will prevent your game from being minimize when clicking the two mouse buttons at the same time.

#### How to Disable Windows Flip 3D Completely via Registry - Windows 7

1. Click the **Start** icon
2. Type in `regedit`
3. Select **regedit** from the top of the result
4. Go to: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\DWM`
5. Step to add `DisallowFlip3d` to the registry

   1. Make sure the **DWM** is selected
   2. Right-click on blank area on the right side of the *Regedit* program
   3. Hover over **New**
   4. Select **DWORD (32-bit) Value** from list
   5. Change the name to: `DisallowFlip3d`
   6. Double-click on **DisallowFlip3d** that was just created
   7. Change *Value data* to `1`
   8. Click **OK**
6. Reboot

This is the way to do it without downloading anything. The steps are in detail steps to help both experienced and non-experienced users.

*Disclaimer : You **should** always [backup your registry](http://bit.ly/r0edt8) before editing your registry.*

Comment: I dont have DWM folder in registry

Answer (score 2):

The feature seems to be called `Flip3D`.

It seems that the key combination has been tied to the mouse actions probably with some preinstalled software as this is not enable in Windows by default.

However I found a [solution](http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-turn-off-and-disable-windows-flip-3d-switcher-in-vista/) to disable the feature, albeit a bit overkill but it should work.

[Howtogeek](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/disable-flip3d-in-windows-vista/) explaination.